# ImageWriter to MediaRecorder failed with "Color format is not recoganized. Format 0x113"

Tags: android, android-camera2, mediarecorder

I am trying to alter image buffer from camera2 api and direct the altered image into MediaRecorder. Here is what I do:

```
ImageReader imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                                    cameraSize.getWidth(),
                                    cameraSize.getHeight(),
                                    ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);
// createCaptureSession with imageReader.getSurface()
imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(reader -> {
                                Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                                if (image == null) {
                                    return;
                                }

                                ImageWriter imageWriter = ImageWriter.newInstance(mediaRecorder.getSurface(), 2);

                                imageWriter.queueInputImage(image);
                                imageWriter.close();
                                image.close();
});
```

MediaRecorder is setup like this:

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
       
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path);

mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(RECORDER_VIDEO_BITRATE);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mCameraSize.getWidth(), mCameraSize.getHeight());
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

When I run this code, I get error message "Color format is not recoganized. Format 0x113", which is HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV21_ZSL. I don't understand and don't know how to solve it.

What I've tried is, to change the image format of ImageReader.newInstance and ImageWriter.newInstance to several others, turned out I got the same error message anyway.